# Bootstrap Carousel Image size and placement issues with xs (mobile) devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel

I know there's a lot of questions on here about Bootstrap Carousel image size issues, but I haven't found a solution to the problem I'm having. I'm honestly not sure where the problem stems, as this is my first time using Bootstrap.

I have a carousel that I plan to display eight different images, all of various widths and heights. For now, I have the height of the images at 500px or less, for test purposes. The carousel I have now looks... fair on my 1080p laptop. The position of the indicators are a bit off, though I don't know if that can be altered. The biggest problem I'm having right now is how it looks on a mobile device (I'm using an iPhone5c for testing.) I've set the style to each image style to `"object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;"` and used the `"img-responsive"` class, yet, on mobile, the images do not resize for some reason. I really don't know where to start when it comes to fixing this Carousel.

Test page is here: http://mcthompson.info/suzaku/index.html

Here's the code that's uploaded right now that pertains to just the carousel. Any help would be appreciated:

**HTML**

```
        <div class="container" id='indexslide'>
        <div id="main_slide" class="carousel slide" data-ride='carousel'>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="item1 active"></li>
                    <li class="item2"></li>
                    <li class="item3"></li>
                    <li class="item4"></li>
                    <li class="item5"></li>
                    <li class="item6"></li>
                    <li class="item7"></li>
                    <li class="item8"></li>
                </ol>
                <!--slides-->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="width:100%; height: 510px !important;">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src='babyhuck1.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Baby Huck</h3>
                        <p>Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='bamboo1.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Bamboo</h3>
                        <p>2 Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='magnolias1.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Magnolias</h3>
                        <p>3 Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='peacock1.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Peacock</h3>
                        <p>4 Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='maiko.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Maiko</h3>
                        <p>5 Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='waterlillies.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Water Lilies</h3>
                        <p>6 Demo text blah blah blah <a href=image3.JPG>CLICK</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='cityscape1a.jpg' style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;" alt>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Cityscape 1</h3>
                        <p>7 Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src='cosmos1.jpg' alt style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Cosmos 1</h3>
                        <p>8 Demo text blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main_slide" role="button" data-slide='prev'>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>

              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main_slide" role="button" data-slide='next'>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: none;
}

/* Mobile */
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: auto;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
         width: 80%;
    }
}

/* tablets */
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: auto;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

/* laptops */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: 200px;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
        width: 60%;
    }
}

/* desktops */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
        width: 60%;
    }
}

/*slide caption*/
.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-family: 'Della Respira', serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a bootply showing a functioning bootstrap carousel using img-responsive.

It can be done entirely using bootstrap. After looking at your code there is something that is causing a conflict with the img-responsive class, but I was unable to find it. I suggest replacing your carousel code with that in the bootply, if it works correctly then simply just put in your own images and add captions.

http://www.bootply.com/VSBjMEUu1Z

Comment: Okay, I've replaced the carousel with the one in your bootply. In addition, a friend of mine tried to see if he could fix the issue. We also added some code to adjust the chevrons on mobile. The main issue I have right now is that on an actual mobile device, the image is sized right but there is some cutting off on the right side. We changed some of the sizing to `vw` rather than `px`, which is supposed to adapt to any screen size. Have no clue what's causing this.

Here's the carousel w/ full css
http://www.bootply.com/8YDeq52yJc

Comment: When you say there is some cutting off on the right side, do you mean the image is going off the screen? Or the carousel itself is cutting out a bit of the image on the right?

Comment: The carousel itself is cutting off some of the image.

Comment: There must be some css rule that is either affecting the image or the carousel. Have you got anything such as min-width attached to the images?